# How to prove $\frac{2^a+3}{2^a-9}$ is not a natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I prove that

$$\frac{2^a+3}{2^a-9}$$

for $a \in \mathbb N$ is never a natural number?

Comment: thanks to all, that was really stupid :P

Comment: $a>3$ to get a positive number. Then $19/7\notin\mathbb N$ and the next ones are below $2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{2^a+3}{2^a-9}=1+\frac{12}{2^a-9}$$

So $\frac{12}{2^a-9}$ must be a natural number as well.

Comment: Sweet solution!

Answer (score 6):

$$1+\frac{12}{2^a-9}$$

which means that $2^a$ should equal either $10,11,12,13,15$ or $21$, but neither of them is a power of $2$, so it's never a natural number

Comment: You forgot $2^a=21$, but that isn't a power of two either.

Comment: @rajb245 thanks, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The expression is equivalent to $$1+\frac{12}{2^n-9}$$ so there aren't many cases to consider.

Comment: Thanks wythagoras. Looks like you're a bit faster typing mathjax than me!

Answer (score 2):

Define the natural numbers to be the set $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. Assume $\frac{2^a+3}{2^a-9}$ is a natural number, then so is $$1+\frac{12}{2^a-9},$$ and 
$$\frac{2^a+3}{2^a-9}-1=\frac{12}{2^a-9}\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}.$$
But $$\frac{12}{2^a-9}\not\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}.$$ Contradiction. Similar argument holds if you assume $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: but $$2^3-9=8-9=-1$$ and $$12/(-1)=-12$$ is surely an integer

Comment: and $-12\not\geq 0$... !

Comment: yes it must be naturel number that i true

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively...

If $\displaystyle \frac{2^a+3}{2^a-9} = k$ for some integer $k$, then

$$(k-1)2^a = -12$$ or $$2^a = 12/(1-k).$$ As $2^a = 2, 4, 8, ...$, the only possible values for $k$ are $k = -5, -2$. But these are not natural numbers as they are negative integers.